# TinyMce v.6 how to remove "br" tags added after each paragraph

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm using version 6 of TinyMce and I can't find a way to avoid adding `<br>` after each paragraph

Inserting a line of text and pressing enter creates a new paragraph, but a `<br>` is always added between one and the other.
In the old versions it was enough to add these two parameters:

- force_p_newlines = true;
- forced_root_block = false;

But now both are deprecated and I can't find a way to achieve the same result

The guide says that **force_p_newlines** is no longer available that **forced_root_block** should be used instead, but even setting forced_root_block: "p" which should already be like this by default, nothing changes

I tried to change the default tag which is `<p>` with a `<div>`, but I always find the `<br>` nested between the various divs in the output.

My current initialization is:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector:'#myTextarea',
  plugins: "link",
  toolbar: "undo redo | bold italic link ",
  menubar: false,
  forced_root_block: "p",
    forced_root_block_attrs: {
      class: "m-0",
    },
  force_br_newlines: false,
});
```

I'm using bootstrap 5 and I've used the **forced_root_block_attrs** attribute to eliminate paragraph margins by attributing class "m-0" to all `<p>` tags

Answer (score 1):

```
    tinymce.init({
  selector:'#myTextarea',
  plugins: "link",
  toolbar: "undo redo | bold italic link ",
  menubar: false,
  forced_root_block: "",
    forced_root_block_attrs: {
      class: "m-0",
    },
  force_br_newlines: true,
force_p_newlines: false,
});

try this may be work?
```

Comment: no, it doesn't work and as mentioned force_p_newlines and forced_root_block (false only) are deprecated

Comment: thats all i know about this!

Comment: OK Do not worry ;) Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

I solved it as follows, I'm using tinymce 6

```js
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#editor-texto',
    language: 'pt_BR',
    plugins: 'anchor autolink charmap codesample emoticons image link lists media searchreplace table visualblocks wordcount',
    toolbar: 'undo redo | blocks fontfamily fontsize | bold italic underline strikethrough | link image media table | align lineheight | numlist bullist indent outdent | emoticons charmap | removeformat',
    forced_root_block: true,
    setup: function(editor) {
      editor.on('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
          e.preventDefault();

          tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('InsertLineBreak');
        }
      });
    }
  });
```